# Swift: show name in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have array with names in `TableViewController` and I have `ViewController`. If I click on cell in `TableViewController` I want to show name from array in `ViewController` navigation bar title. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Storyboard`, and want to navigate and pass "title" to the *SecondViewController*:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let name = YOUR_ARRAY[indexPath.row]

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_SECOND_VIEW_IDENTIFIER") as? SecondViewController else { return}
    destinationVC.title = name
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}
```

If you use `Interface Builder`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let name = YOUR_ARRAY[indexPath.row]

    let destinationVC = SecondViewController(nibName: "YOUR_SECOND_VIEW_NAME", bundle: nil)
    destinationVC.title = name
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    navigationItem.title = myArray[indexPath.row]

}
```

UPDATE:

If you are using storyboards, you can:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let ame = myArray[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController", sender: selectedName)

}
```

then, recover the `selectedName` in `prepareForSegue` and set the title for destinationVC there:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let selectedName = sender as? String,
    let viewController = segue.destination as? ViewController {
      detailViewController.navigationItem.title = selectedName
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I use code in `TableViewController` I show name in `TableViewController` navigation bar. But I need to show name in `ViewController` from `TableViewController` array.

Comment: I missunderstood your question, have now updated the answer for a solution if you are using storyboards. You can pass the selectedName through the sender or save it as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can set title of viewcontroller by

suppose you have a view Controller

```
class UIViewController{
  // make a variable in your view controller like
 var titleName:String?

 override func viewDidLoad(){
   self.tittle = self.titleName
 }
}
```

from your tableViewController you can pass the name to your ViewController

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let controller = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass you view controller storyboard id here") as! ViewController
controller.titleName = yourArray[indexPath.row]
self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller , animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: If I use code in `TableViewController` I show name in `TableViewController` navigation bar. But I need to show name in `ViewController` from `TableViewController` array

Comment: then you can pass name from your tableview controller to your vew controller and then set the title in viewDidLoad method

Comment: How to do this?